# When I push a cpp file to the github repository then an exe file gets added. What can I do so that I don't get those exe files

Tags: github

Whenever I push a cpp file to my github repository an exe file gets added to the repository. I don't want that exe file.How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

you want the file not be tracked across everyone's repositories create a pattern as below in `.gitignore` file. This file can either be in root directory of you application or a the directory you .cpp and .exe files are in.

```
*.exe
```

If you want .exe files to be ignored for only you. Then you can put above pattern in `.git/info/exclude`

Follow this link for more info:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore

Comment: Thanks for the help! I added a .gitignore file in the repository and inside that *.exe and now I am not getting any exe files.